# Return String variable delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page with a table identified by `"table-rank"` class.
This table has 3 pages : to go on next page, i use the `.click` function on the net button.

I tried to build a finalHtml string by capturing specific element in each lines of the table.

**Problem :** The finalHtml contains 3 times the datas of the first page of the table. No data of the second page and third page is captured..

It's because, when i click on the button, it's asynchronous, and the first loop continue to parse the table which have not been already refreshed. How can i do, to be sure that the data have been loaded when i click on the next button ?

```
function getClassement() {

    var finalHtml = '' ;

    for (var k=0; k<2; k++) {

        for (var i=0; i<$(".table-rank tbody tr").length; i++) {

            var currentLine = $(".table-rank tbody tr")[i];

            // Get position
            var positionEl = $(currentLine).find(".ng-binding")[0];
            var position = $(positionEl).text();

            // Get id
            var idEl = $(currentLine).find(".ng-binding")[1];
            var id = $(idEl).text();

            // Get prenom/nom
            var nomPrenom = "test";

            // Nombre de paris
            var nbrParisEl = $(currentLine).find(".ng-binding")[2];
            var nbParis = $(nbrParisEl).text();

            // Nombre de bons paris
            var nbrBonsParisEl = $(currentLine).find(".ng-binding")[3];
            var nbBonsParis = $(nbrBonsParisEl).text();

            // Score exacts
            var scoresExactsEl = $(currentLine).find(".ng-binding")[4];
            var scoresExacts = $(scoresExactsEl).text();

            // Points totals
            var pointsTotalEl = $(currentLine).find(".ng-binding")[7];
            var pointsTotals = $(pointsTotalEl).text();

            finalHtml = finalHtml + "<tr><td><span class='position'>"+position+"</span></td><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+nomPrenom+"</td><td>"+nbParis+"</td><td>"+nbBonsParis+"</td><td>"+scoresExacts+"</td><td><span class='total'>"+pointsTotals+"</span></td></tr>";

        }

        // Go next page
        $(".pager a")[1].click();

    }

    return finalHtml;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't going onto another page terminate the script, thus causing each page to start at the beginning of the loop again?

Comment: when i go on next page, after few seconds, the table is refresh with next values.